# Am I using Stack Overflow wrong?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Sorry for the click bait title.

We've all been there. You ask a question and received a downvote. I don't disagree with the downvote mechanic, it was invented for a reason. But it still stings.

OK, so say: I get stuck with a problem. I fiddle around with it for three hours, maybe three days, or whatnot turning the Internet inside out. So finally as I am ready to give up I come to Stack Overflow to get some help.

But the problem remains that had I been able to to identify the exact domain of the problem I probably wouldn't be in this grease to begin with.

I usually don't ask for help (irrelevant). But when I finally do... DOWNVOTES! Glorious down votes. I'm a sour looser, but perhaps I confuse "*downvote*".

Look at the section "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research."

- What have you tried?
- Have you looked elsewhere?

But this list is NOT useful advice. I followed it and had questions front loaded with links and tons of information I had previously been digging up for the last three hours. So to answer those two simply is What have you tried? Everything? Where have you looked? Everywhere? No. I just simply omit that those pieces and try to isolate the core of the problem. Usually failing.

The problems with my questions would normally be:

- Question is vague
- Answer is open ended
- Terminology is different for each domain
- I don't understand the problem
- I don't understand the domain

So I guess I should understand what IS Stack Overflow and what it is NOT. Perhaps what I'm asking for a is a community of people providing help instead of answers?

Comment: This is really broad. Can you narrow your question down? What do you actually need help with? If you're looking for a definition of Stack Overflow or an explanation of how it works, that's much, much more than can be answered reasonably here.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Did you check our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before ask this question? If you did, then I think you know what's the problem.

Comment: Just FYI, the click-bait title is probably attracting downvotes. So is the broadness of the question, as pointed out. But mostly, it's the complaining about downvotes, a sure way to attract *more* downvotes here on Meta. The good news is, downvotes on Meta don't cost you any rep.

Comment: A nice answer from Cody below. And in your last question, it took 5 hours for the first Answer to arrive for your ability to clarify things under that answer.

Comment: I*. Sorry, I couldn't help it. I know that this is the "meta" section, but do try to proofread sometimes.

Comment: I usually only downvote questions that cannot be answered because the asker was too lazy to provide a [well-formed quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I like questions to at least show an attempt to be good. Questions which are mere duplicates or even stupid questions, are still questions.

Comment: Asking a question on SO then getting an answer on skype is antithetical to the ethos of the site. Questions and answers should benefit more than you.

Comment: Sometimes the very nature of your question can be frustrating for people to answer.  [The last question I've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903830/built-in-word-wrap) has net downvotes on it, even though at least a few people seemed to know what I wanted, and they clearly didn't have an obvious answer, because the answer seems to be "no, it doesn't exist".  My current theory is that difficult to impossible questions are very frustrating for people who are trying to answer it, and those people are the ones who are there to vote.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> i get stuck with a problem. I fiddle around with it for 3 hours maybe 3 days or whatnot turning the internet inside out. So finally as i am ready to give up i come to SO to get some help.
>
> But the problem remains that had i been able to to identify the exact domain of the problem i probably wouldn't be in this grease to begin with.
>
> I usually don't ask for help (irrelevant). But when i finally do... DOWN VOTES! glorious down votes. I'm a sour looser but perhaps i confuse "down vote".

This certainly makes it sound like you are doing things right. You are trying to solve a problem by yourself, you are doing some debugging to isolate the source of the problem, and you are doing some of your own research first before asking the question. Still unsuccessful, you ask a question. So far, so good.

And then you get a downvote. Again, no big deal. I don't know why you are "stung" so much by a single downvote. They're not a way for people to reach through the Internet and slap you in the face. You need to stop taking downvotes so personally. A downvote means, as per the tooltip, either that the question is unclear, not useful, or shows no research effort. Naturally, votes represent the subjective opinion of the voter. There are things you can do to help ensure that your question will be broadly appealing, but there is absolutely nothing you can do to make yourself immune from downvotes.

> The problems with my questions would normally be:
>
> - Question is vague
> - Answer is open ended
> - Terminology is different for each domain
> - I don't understand the problem
> - I don't understand the domain
>
> So i guess i should understand what IS Stackoverflow and what it is NOT.

But then this makes it sound like you are actually asking the wrong type of question. Our guidelines for [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are pretty clear. If your questions fall into the categories you've enumerated, then they are really not welcome here. If you keep asking them, you can continue to expect a negative response (not just in terms of downvotes, but also in terms of having your questions closed and eventually deleted).

> Perhaps what I'm asking for a is a community of people providing help instead of answers?

Sorry, we don't do that here. This is a *question and answer* site. We provide *answers*. Many people find answers to be helpful, so we've become a massive success by employing this model.

If you are not looking for answers, then you will be extremely frustrated by this site. We don't do tutorials, we won't hold your hand while you write code or learn a new language, we won't answer broad-reaching and open-ended questions about the future of programming or new technologies. If you want those things, I'm sure there are places on the Internet that can provide them. Stack Overflow is, however, not such a place.

---

Let's look at some specifics. The most recent (non-deleted) questions you've asked are:

- [Can't render simple transparent sprites in SharpGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865203/sharpgl-rendering-simple-sprites-alpha-specific)

  This question is, topically, just fine. It asks about a specific programming problem, and even includes some code. Looks reasonable. But it's been downvoted, so clearly it has *some* kind of problem. The answer it has received gives some clue as to what that problem might be. Namely, it is incredibly vague. Aside from a code dump and a couple of images, there is literally no explanation about what you are trying to accomplish. What isn't working? What you want to make work? The title doesn't make much sense (it is not even a question), and the question *"How do I make the alpha work in my PNG?"* is about the most vague question you could ever ask. What do you mean by "work"? What isn't working? What would "working" look like? No one can tell from your question.
- [Locking Frames Per Second to 60fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028880/locking-frames-per-second-to-60fps)

  This question is also topical, and much more specific (*i.e.*, less vague). Not coincidentally, it hasn't been downvoted. The only thing wrong here is basically that you're asking to do something impossible. 60 fps is not something you're likely to achieve in WinForms. That *could* get you some downvotes, but it's more likely to just cause the question to go unanswered. Few people are willing to post Scott Chamberlain's comment in the answer box. Such answers are often poorly received, doubly so by the person who asked the question, so experts just move along and answer another question instead.
- [SQLite.NET causes reappearing and inconsistent problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868040/sqlite-net-causes-reappearing-and-inconsistent-problems)

  I have no real idea what this question is about, but that's not your fault. It is mine: I know nothing about SQLite. But it looks like a valid question, and it has been upvoted twice. No obvious problems here.
- [Is logging an exception into a MessageBox a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080404/is-logging-an-exception-into-a-messagebox-a-good-practice)

  Uh oh, now we have a problem. This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow, and it has been rightly closed as "primarily opinion-based." The close reason should be a sufficient explanation as to what's wrong with this type of question and why we don't allow them, so I won't rehash it here. And I doubt this is one that you researched extensively before posting, as there is lots of advice already available on the Internet about handling exceptions. I know for a fact that I have posted comprehensive answers to Stack Overflow about good exception-handling practices on at least two separate occasions. You should have been able to find at least one of those. I bet there are lots of people with blogs who have written about this topic, too.

It looks to me like your real problem is not downvotes, but just the fact that you have not received answers. This is a scaling problem—the questions asked per-day vastly outnumbers the individuals willing and able to answer those questions. You can improve your odds by making your questions interesting, easy to find (well titled and tagged), and extremely clear. There is no perfect strategy, but failure to receive an answer doesn't necessarily mean you're doing anything wrong.

Comment: Absolutely brilliantly elaborate and detailed answer! All in all, YES i am using Stackoverflow wrong which explains much. It would seem that my problem is the way i use terminology and expect mutual understanding. Should i spend a small section in top of the question explaining "What is Alpha?" or "What is a sprite?"?

Comment: So no Stackoverflow is not a "get help" website. So questions that need 3 follow questions belong elsewhere. I hope i can find a different outlet for that.

Comment: I know what alpha blending is and what sprites are.  You just forgot to ask a question in your question.  I assume you expect to see your first image tiled in a 10x10 grid in the second image, but that's just a guess.  "make alpha work in my PNG" sounds like you're having a problem generating PNGs, but the images suggest you want to use one as a texture and are not declaring the right texture format (hence the diagonal lines in the second image).  Or maybe you think the problem is with your input PNG, not the code that uses it?

Comment: What Jeffrey said. You can assume that people know the definitions of standard programming terms, like alpha-blending, sprites, and that kind of thing. You cannot assume that they know what you are trying to do. This is the hard part of asking questions. You have to re-read your question, pretending that you have amnesia and have forgotten everything you know about the problem—does the question still make sense? If not, it needs more details.  @cyber

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Going a bit off topic but your guess is correct. Input is correct output is unexpected. Where the world i come from in higher levels of abstraction i never had a single worry about alpha channels. Load image file -> Display image But the place i fall short is I'm being expected just implicitly understand that i must "blend" them in order to get any result. I'm 100% sure this problem is so easy any OGL beginner can do it. But I'm failing to describe or even realize the unknown steps between Load file -> See picture.

Comment: @CodyGray the Amnesia tip is really great, left me in thoughts for now.

Comment: "If you are not looking for answers, then you will be extremely frustrated by this site" - Love it.

Comment: If you are looking for examples of accidental humor rather than answers, then you won't be be frustrated.  I think this disproves the quoted statement :-)

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, I faced the same thing when I was new on this site. I hated down-votes. Mine was a mixed emotion (a blend of anger, disappointment and hopelessness maybe). Can you imagine- I received at least 2 downvotes on everything that I posted in the beginning?

I had 2 choices:

- Leave the site and enjoy posting questions on a site which has no voting system.
- Continue with SO.

Why didn't I leave SO?

My ultimate plan was to get some help. It was easily noticeable that some help also accompanied the downvotes which I received. Of course, users downvoted but it didn't stop the answers from coming in. I was here to get help and eventually I learnt that it was also fun to give some help on stackoverflow.

Had I joined some other site, I wouldn't have received the downvotes and probably wouldn't have received good answers as well.The users on other sites are probably looking for a way to express their dislike for the way a question is expressed or formatted but unfortunately they are not given an opportunity to do so. In short, SO is an awesome place to learn and teach as well.

Isn't it amazing that you are at a place where everything is filtered well to give out high quality products to the users. Can you point out a single post on SO which you think is not well defined or worthless?

Everything is going just fine. We have a balanced technique to express our desire to filter out anything that is undesirable/inappropriate or worthless. In the end, what we receive is a well maintained database on programming.I wouldn't step back from calling it a `programming database` since I feel almost everything has an answer on SO. To be precise, high quality answers.

Votes are designed so that other users could actually rate the questions and answers based on their quality. The definition for quality here would be a bit different from what we observe in day to day life.

A low quality question could be:

- something that's not related to programming at all
- How do I bake a cake?
- What is java?
- Should I learn java or start with php?

and so on....

The worst question would be something similar to- `What do you suggest..or..?` So quality has a whole new definition on SO.

Votes are not to be taken personally(no matter downvote or upvote). You aren't actually giving a seminar for people out there to be voting your personality or appearance. The votes are supposed to be pointing towards your posts/answers.

The immediate help you could do to yourself would be to stop considering the life on the internet as a part of your `Real Life`. Virtual life should not be allowed to affect us mentally. We shouldn't let the things that we face on the internet pull us down.

SO helped me improve.

- I have started censoring my works on other sites as well.
- I have become internet conscious.

Comment: You made sense until the last paragraph.